# Forge Viewer - Resizing window with Forge Viewer instance on the background

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Further question on the solution provided [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45354065/3603439). I have a forge viewer that is not rendering on this page but it is running in the background to save (re)loading  at continuous route changes. But when I resize the page, It gives me below error on this page.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '__webglFramebuffer' of null

Is there any way to block forge viewer "resize" from getting called?

P.S. I don't want to destroy the viewer. As I want it load on the background.

Comment: Well the viewer code is listening for the window resize event to run some logic upon it, so I don't think there is a way to disable that unless you patch the API with a custom version. On the other side this error will be fired only when the viewer is not visible, so it seems not a big issue except noise in the browser console...