# How to save/load model from/to browser cache in forge autodesk

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

In our app, it's quite common that a user would look at a 3d model, navigates to some other place, and come back to the model.
When the user navigates away, I'm destroying the viewer as recommended in this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45354065/getting-webgl-error-in-autodesk-viewer)

Every time the user wants to come back to the model, it seems that the viewer tries to re-download it and then display it.
[image: requests fired by forge]

It takes 10-15s to load the model with a good internet connection. However, since everything should have already been download, is there a way avoid making these requests and load the model directly from the browser cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently published a blog post on leveraging service workers and new cache APIs to cache Forge content locally: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/disconnected-workflows.

Comment: I get "Page Not Found Sorry, but we could not find this page"... I tried to google for your blog post but same thing

Comment: Sorry @Gpack, the site is currently experiencing issues. Try the link a little later.

Comment: Btw. the site is back online.